# Label tag should keep on top when input value is not empty

Tags: javascript

I have created an onClick label toggle effect, but facing one issue that, when user type/input any value in the input box label should be kept on top and not over lapping on value or down.

`you will find`  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rupesx26/vzcxa7jq/)

Js code

```
function move(elem){
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('label')
        for(i=0; i< a.length; i++){
            a[i].classList.remove('active');
        }
        elem.classList.add('active');

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add relevant code to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a nice effect, and you can accomplish the same thing in CSS without using any JavaScript.

The code below changes the label's style if the input field is focused or has a value.

Note that the label needs `pointer-events: none` so that the input behind it can be focused when the label is clicked:

```css
.input-field {
  margin:50px;
  position:relative;
  width:204px;
}

input {
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  width:200px;
  height:3rem;
  font-size:1rem;
  position:relative;
}

label {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: text;
  font-size: 1rem;
  left: 0rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.8rem;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
}

.input-field input:not(:invalid) + label,
.input-field input:focus + label {
  background: yellow; 
  top: -35px;
  font-size:0.7rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-field">
  <input type="text" name="name" required="">
  <label>First Name</label>
</div>

<div class="input-field">
  <input type="text" name="name" required="">
  <label>Last Name</label>
</div>
```

---

The above won't work if you need to support <=IE9.  In that case, you *will* need to use JavaScript.

Attach `focus` and `blur` events to the inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="name" required="" 
       onfocus="ifocus(this)"
       onblur ="iblur(this)"
>

function nextElementSibling(el) {
  do { el = el.nextSibling } while ( el && el.nodeType !== 1 );
  return el;
}

function ifocus(el) {
  nextElementSibling(el).className= 'active';
}

function iblur(el) {
  if(!el.value.trim()) {
    nextElementSibling(el).className= '';
  }
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9yuzpgm2/)

Also note that the `rem` units won't work in <=IE8, and the `transition` won't work in <=IE9.  If you want the animation to work in those versions, you'll need to write it completely in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably want to use `focus` and `blur` events for this.

Answer (score 0):

call the move function in the onfocus(); event. And a note, You shouldn't use the inline calling methods. You should use an event listener.

something like

```
document.getElementById('elementId').addEventListener('focus',move);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well question is not clear still am trying. 
From your fiddle I see issue that once value in entered, label shouldn't come down as its doing now. If so

```
function move(elem){
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('label')
    elem.classList.add('active');
}
```

will be a better option.

Comment: Thanks for your time @ashish451, But I think you got my point.. when you saw the fiddle